# Finding whole number answers from whole number inputs

Tags: elementary-number-theory

How could I find out if the following equation produces a whole number result (*y*) using only whole number inputs (*x*).

6y = 2^x

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Remark:** Whole numbers usually means the same thing as integers.

For the equation $6y = 2^x$ where $x$ is an integer, in order for $y$ to be an integer, $2^x$ must be evenly divisible by $6$. However, there does not exist such an $x$, and here is why:

The prime factorization of $6$ is $3*2$ and the prime factorization of $2^x$ is $2^x$, because $2$ is prime and we are just multiplying $2$ several times for $x \geq 2$. Because there is no $3$ in the prime factorization of $2^x$, no power of $2$ is divisible by 6.

For negative $x$, we only get fractions, i.e., $y = \frac{1}{6*2^x}$ which is not an integer.

Comment: Integer, I knew that. I'm learning that the calibre of this forum is very high and I don't need to dumb down my questions.

I understand what you mean by prime factorization (I think) in that you break the coefficients down into their smallest parts, essentially, and I see how your explanation answers my question, but I'm curious if you could explain how you knew to used prime factorization. 

What was your process? 

What are the triggers that told you how to figure this out?

Thank you for your answer.

Comment: @greer.kenneth I noticed you would probably know as a programmer, after I answered, and your intuition is correct. It is by definitions that primes are not evenly divisible by any integer beside itself and $1$. Consider how for all integers $a$, $b$, and $c$ that $\frac{ac}{ab} = c/b$, which results in an integer unless $c$ is a multiple of $b$. Thus, if we want an integer, the entire denominator must be canceled when we have prime numbers. Furthermore, no two positive integers share the same prime factorization as proved in the fundamental theorem of arithmetic, i.e., factorization is unique.

Comment: Also, my trigger was immediate -- most of MSE is familar with these integer theorems. You can probably get good at mathematical proofs through Google, MSE, and Wikipedia. Just dedicate time.

Answer (score 0):

You can find out by trying out some values for $x$. For instance, for $x=1$, you get $6y=2$, which has no integer solution.

Comment: I was looking for a more definitive answer without the rigor of going through each number. I was looking for *prime factorization* but I didn't know that's what I needed for my definitive answer. 

Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

The left hand side contains the prime factor $3$, while the right hand side doesn't. Conclude.

Comment: I appreciate your brevity and confirmation of the used of prime factorization. Do you have any tip/tricks for spotting answers that need prime factorization?

Comment: If you can factor both sides of the equation, then prime factorization is a natural tool.